# mercurial-server pretxncommit hook not working

Tags: mercurial-hook, mercurial-server

Server

```
$ hg --version
    Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 2.0.2)

/usr/share/mercurial-server$ cat mercurial_server-1.1.egg-info
    Metadata-Version: 1.1
    Name: mercurial-server
    Version: 1.1

$ cat /etc/mercurial-server/remote-hgrc.d/check.rc 
    [ui]
    debug = true

    [hooks]
    commit.h1 = echo "executing commit USER:$REMOTE_USER"
    precommit.h2 = echo "executing precommit USER:$REMOTE_USER"
    pretxncommit.h3 = echo "executing pretxncommit USER:$REMOTE_USER"
    pretxnchangegroup.h4 = echo "executing pretxnchangegroup USER:$REMOTE_USER"
```

local machine

```
unity@unity:~/hgtst/hgadmin$ vi keys/users/user.m/user.m.pub 
unity@unity:~/hgtst/hgadmin$ hg commit -m "Test L"
unity@unity:~/hgtst/hgadmin$ hg push
    pushing to ssh://hg@repo/hgadmin
    searching for changes
    remote: adding changesets
    remote: changesets: 1 chunks
    remote: add changeset 9cb298911d0c
    remote: adding manifests
    remote: manifests: 1/1 chunks (100.00%)
    remote: adding file changes
    remote: adding keys/users/user.m/user.m.pub revisions
    remote: files: 1/1 chunks (100.00%)
    remote: added 1 changesets with 1 changes to 1 files
    remote: calling hook pretxnchangegroup.access: mercurialserver.access.hook
    remote: running hook pretxnchangegroup.h4: echo "executing pretxnchangegroup USER:$REMOTE_USER"
    remote: executing pretxnchangegroup USER:
    remote: updating the branch cache
    remote: calling hook changegroup.aaaaa_servelog: mercurialserver.servelog.hook
    remote: running hook changegroup.aaaab_update: hg update -C default > /dev/null
    remote: running hook changegroup.aaaac_purge: hg purge --all > /dev/null
    remote: calling hook changegroup.refreshauth: mercurialserver.refreshauth.hook
unity@unity:~/hgtst/hgadmin$
```

when I push some changes from local machine to the mercurial-server via ssh pretxnchangegroup hook is executed but no other hook is getting executed.

Answer (score 2):

This is to be expected.
You don't commit at the remote server, you push changes to it.
That's what `changegroup` is for, which you are using.

To me it seems like everything is working like it should.

Hope this helps, TW